# How to listen when jQuery widget is being disabled / enabled?

Tags: jquery-ui, events, widget, jquery

I want to know how can I detect that jQuery widget is being disabled or enabled ?
ie.

```
$(input).spinner("disable");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible, because jQuery widgets do not listen for option change events, such as enable and disable, by default.